# unable to find `as` method in `Config`

Tags: playframework-2.6

I saw the following code snippet

```
   val settings = configuration.underlying.as[CookieSecretSettings]("silhouette.oauth1TokenSecretProvider")
```

I believe configuration is of type `play.api.Configuration` and `underlying is of type`Config` (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.Configuration)

I copied the code in my Apploader (as I am using Compile Time Injection). The `BuiltInComponentsFromContext` has a `configuration` variable. I thought to use that as follows `val config = configuration.underlying.as[CookieAuthenticatorSettings]("silhouette.authenticator")` but the compiler cannot resolve `as`. What am I doing wrong?

The Config library seem to have `asInstanceOf` instead of `as` but I get other errors if I use that. I notice that the code for which `as` works uses `play` version `2.4.2` while I am using `2.6.12`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but I stumbled upon this exact problem today and couldn't find anything helpful.

The `as` method is provided by a third-party library ([Ficus](https://github.com/iheartradio/ficus)) to read case classes and Scala types from Typesafe config. You need to include it in your build dependencies, then add to imports:

```
import net.ceedubs.ficus.Ficus._
import net.ceedubs.ficus.readers.ArbitraryTypeReader._
```

Comment: thanks. I'll check but it might take me some time to do it. I'll provisionally accept the answer till then